# Electrolysis of concentrated sodium chloride solution using A.C. power supply

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, electrolysis

I heard that A.C current is never used for electrolysis as the polarity of the electrodes keep changing and this can result in explosive reactions. However, why can't we use this to our advantage?

When electrolysing brine, chloride ions are discharged at the anode to form chlorine gas and hydrogen ions are reduced at the cathode to form hydrogen gas. When using A.C., the polarity of each electrode would change several times every second (depending on the frequency of current), causing both hydrogen and chlorine to be produced at both electrodes. So in theory, a gas syringe could be set up at each electrode to collect the hydrogen and chlorine, which would then react to form HCl gas which can be collected.

What is wrong with this process? We are able to collect both HCl and NaOH, two very useful compounds. Why is this process not used industrially?

Comment: If H2 is deposited in the first alternance, the same H2 will be consumed in the next alternation, and redissolved. Sam thing on the second electrode, with Cl2 that get deposited, then redissolved in the next alternation.  Final result : no chemistry at all. Just a Joule effect, to increase the temperature.

Comment: Oh that's interesting, I didn't think of that. So all the electrical energy from the A.C. power supply is converted to thermal energy?

Comment: Think about the frequency of AC current. It changes its direction so many times in a $second$. Can anyone manually move the syringe that fast?

Comment: Technically, there would be no need to move the syringe at all. There will be a syringe at each electrode and both syringes will collect HCl gas